# Add 2 ActionResult DeleteConfirmed in 1 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to have 2 ActionResult DeleteConfirmed in 1 controller?

I have 2 different views that I want to delete.

Thanks,
EB

```
                [HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteLink")]
                public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
                {
                    Link link = db.Links.Find(id);
                    db.Links.Remove(link);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("OutOfBank");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to overload `DeleteConfirmed` action. You can use the attribute if you want your code to do overloading.

```
[ActionName("MyOverloadedName")]
```

But, you'll have to use a different action name for the same http method.
 So it's just semantics at that point. Would you rather have the name in your code or your attribute?

Code Example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetEmpName()
    {
        return Content("This is the test Message");
    }

    [ActionName("GetEmpWithCode")]
    public ActionResult GetEmpName(string EmpCode)
    {
        return Content("This is the test Messagewith Overloaded");
    }
}
```

Phil has an article related to this: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx